# Trouble using all members in a class. Why can I only use the list?

Tags: c#, class

I have the following class object structure:

```
public class StatusObj3
{
    public int status { get; set; }
    public DataObj3 data { get; set; }
}

public class DataObj3
{
    public string survey_id { get; set; }
    public string date_created { get; set; }
    public string date_modified { get; set; }
    public int custom_variable_count { get; set; }
    public List<Custom_VariablesObj> custom_variables { get; set; }
    public int language_id { get; set; }
    public int num_responses { get; set; }
    public int question_count { get; set; }
    public string nickname { get; set; }
    public TitleObj title { get; set; }
    public List<PagesObj> pages { get; set; }
}

public class Custom_VariablesObj
{
    public string variable_label { get; set; }
    public string question_id { get; set; }
}

public class TitleObj
{
    public bool enabled { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class PagesObj
{
    string page_id { get; set; }
    string heading { get; set; }
    string sub_heading { get; set; }
    public List<QuestionObj> questions { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionObj
{
    public string question_id { get; set; }
    public string heading { get; set; }
    public string position { get; set; }
    public QuestionTypeObj type { get; set; }
    public List<AnswerObj> answers { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionTypeObj
{
    public string family { get; set; }
    public string subtype { get; set; }
}

public class AnswerObj
{
    public string answer_id { get; set; }
    public int position { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public bool visible { get; set; }
    public int weight { get; set; }
    public bool apply_all_rows { get; set; }
    public bool is_answer { get; set; }
    public List<ItemsObj> items { get; set; }
}

public class ItemsObj
{
    public string answer_id { get; set; }
    public int position { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

I 've deserialized json into this object via:

```
   var results_SurveyDetails = deserializer.Deserialize<StatusObj3>(json_returned);
```

I'm trying to loop thru the pages by:

```
    foreach (var page in results_SurveyDetails.data.pages)
```

However, not all members of page are available to use.
Only the page.questions is there and not page_id, heading and subheading.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pages is the only Object not cooperating. All further levels have all members present.

Comment: What does the source JSON look like?

Comment: it's not a json issue. And it's obvious now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `public` on your other properties in class `PagesObj`.